# Getting an error: Invalid prop `value` supplied to `TextField` when passing object as value to <select>

Tags: forms, reactjs, material-ui

I have a select menu populated with available companies from my database. When the user clicks one of the companies I would like the to set the state of the selectedCompany to that company object.

This works with my implementation. However, React complains with the following error.

> Invalid prop `value` supplied to `TextField`

Here's my

```
   <TextField
          id="selectedCompany"
          select
          label="Select a company"
          margin="normal"
          className={classes.textFieldSelect}
          value={props.selectedCompany === null ? "" : props.selectedCompany}
          onChange={props.handleInputChange('selectedCompany')}
          SelectProps={{
            MenuProps: {
              className: classes.menu,
            },
            name: "selectedCompany"
          }}
          helperText="Example: Company 1"
        >
          {props.availableCompanies.map((company, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={index} value={company}>
              {company.name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
  </TextField>
```

And the relevant functions in my parent component:

```
export class Jobs extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          currentJob: {
             selectedCompany: null,
          }
          availableCompanies: [],
        };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}

  handleInputChange = name => e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.value;
    console.log(value);

    this.setState({ currentJob: { ...this.state.currentJob, [name]: value } });
  };
```

}

Comment: Check the value of `selectedCompany` at each point to make sure you are passing a valid value and it is not undefined.  `undefined !== null`

Comment: What is `selectedCompany`? the API says that it should be a string or a number.

Comment: selectedCompany is an object. It works fine but the API complains. I wonder if there is any clever workaround to avoid the error in the console.

selectedCompany is null initially and then set to the state of the selected company afterwards.

Comment: It complains because you're using it wrong. It should be a string or a number by definition.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to set the value of the currently selected object to the entire object instead of just a string from the object what would be the best way to do this?